# How to click on a button in hovecard

Tags: javascript

Problem: I go into a facebook group members page. Here, I search for members.
Result is a list of facebook accounts. 
When mouse over an account, a hovercard appears, there's a Request button (friend request) that I want to click to send friend request to that person.

Normally, if the Request buttons appear directly on the page (not each Request button on each hovercard), then I can use the below code to auto click all of them (see attached img1 below):

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 FriendRequestAdd addButton _4jy3 _517h'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }
```

Question: how to click all Request buttons on hovercards of all facebook accounts in the result list I mentioned above. I investigated javascript, html, css and have not found the solution yet, because I don't know how to get the element in hovercard (see attached img2 below).
Please help me, thank you so much!

I attach images for your reference.

[img1: auto click Request button directly on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeyhX.png)

[img2: how to click Request button on hovercard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEorQ.png)

Comment: Interesting problem

Comment: I think it should be similar as this: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/174549 . Install tampermonkey chrome extension then install the script (unfriend multiple friends). I'm investigating this script. Hope that I can figure out the solution for mine.

Comment: Is there any idea everyone?